# Link scopes of element and attribute directives

Tags: angularjs

I have element directive, let's say "card". It has value. Also i have attribute directive, let's call it "clickable", that should bind to existing directive scope and add +1 to it's value.

The problem is that scopes of element and attribute directives are different and i need to do scope.$apply() after click.

```
el.on('click', (event) => {
  ctrl.value++;
  console.log('clicked', ctrl.value);
  // i need scope.$apply(); here to update <card>'s value
});
```

I want to attribute directive to not have it's own scope, relying on parent's instead.

try to click on those inputs: http://codepen.io/Fen1kz/pen/GZrgBx?editors=0010

Comment: This has nothing to do with scopes. You're binding to a click event (browser event), you have to use apply afterwards.